# Is it permitted to say Dayan Emet for deceased pet?

Tags: blessing, death, animals

Judging from a few other posts on Mi Yodeya I am left with the impression we do not say anything for a deceased pet. But asking just to be sure.

Comment: With gods name or without?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59839/759

Answer (score 4):

According [to this site](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/01/the-death-of-a-dog-baruch-dayan-haemet/), the answer is superficially yes, but according to one interpretation, no, as a pet is not considered a monetary loss.

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10552/is-it-inappropriate-to-say-baruch-dayan-haemes-on-a-ben-noach-why-or-why-not) seems to point to its being an OK construction for all sorts of sad moments.

And a comment on the [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1582773/jewish/The-Jewish-Blessing-on-Death.htm) website reads that the proper thing to say is "May the Omnipresent One make full your loss (HaMakom Yemalei Chesroncha)" -- see Tractate Berachos 16b".

Answer (score 0):

According to SA (OC 222:2) Baruch Dayan HaEmes is said on any bad news.